# google apis v3 add new calendar using javascript

Tags: javascript, insert, google-calendar-api

I am trying to insert a calendar using javascript:

```
var config = {
        'client_id': client_id,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
    }
gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
           gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
                 var new_calendar = {
                                  id: 'new_calendar'}     
                  request  = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.insert(new_calendar )
                  requestr.execute(function(resp) {
                                   if(!resp.error){
                                        alert('Calendar inserted')
                                   }
                                   return true
                                   })
                  return true
                  })
           return true
           })
   )
```

After authorize succeed I get 404 error on insert request

Thank you

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct Calendar id I don't think 'new_calendar' is a valid calendar id.   Also you appear to be inserting into the calendarList not inserting a new calendar as your question states.  which are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you , I changed gapi.client.calendar.calendarList to gapi.client.calendar.calendar and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct Calendar id I don't think 'new_calendar' is a valid calendar id. Also you appear to be inserting into the [calendarList](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) not inserting a [new calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) as your question states. which are you trying to do?

There is a difference between calendar and calendar list.  The list is on the left hand side of the website.  If you want it displayed you need to add it to the calendar list after you have created the new calendar.